# Java Swing with database connection

Tags: java, database, swing, authentication

Can anyone please help me on how to create a login form in java swing by using a database connection.

Comment: simple and easy tutorial for beginners: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2011/10/create-login-form-using-netbeans-ide.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/login-form-swing.shtml) to create a simple login form. Replace the pseudo pass check with a check of credentials retrieved via JDBC and you're done. The login form is nothing special...

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple login form  and add an event listener to the submit button; and in the handler method write jdbc code to connect to any database.